# Marinade sauce bottle left open for longer than recommended - safe to use?

Tags: food-safety, sauce

I have a marinade bottle from Nandos, it was opened and then kept in a cupboard for about 6 months.

Is it safe to use?

I can't find any information of what could go wrong about sauces. It still smells the same so I don't see any issue aside from the bottle saying:

> Once opened, keep refrigerated and use within 3 months

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it says keep refrigerated and you didn't, I wouldn't chance it. A lot of things need refrigerator temperatures to prevent nasty things from growing and keep them safe. There are also some things that are actually safe unrefrigerated but retain quality better when refrigerated, and will say "keep refrigerated" on the bottle, but you don't really know which is the case here.